# Access table data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to show a list of contacts for the logged in user. But obviously I'm doing something wrong.

I get a error on the contacts list page:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

User.php

```
public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contact::class);
    }
```

Contact.php

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

ContactsController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user_contacts = $user->contacts()
        return view('contacts.list')->with('contacts', $user_contacts);
    }
```

list.blade.php

```
@foreach ($contacts as $contact)
    * {{ $contact->name }} <br>
@endforeach
```

---

Table schema:

**contacts:**

- id
- created_at
- updated_at
- name
- address

**users:**

- id
- name
- password
- remember_token
- created_at
- updated_at

**contact_user:**

- contact_id
- user_id

Comment: Your `User.php` doesn't have any `contacts()` relation function

Comment: Mistake, corrected

Comment: `$user_contacts = $user->contacts()` must be `$user_contacts = $user->contacts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you have the following;

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user_contacts = $user->contacts()
    return view('contacts.list')->with('contacts', $user_contacts);
}
```

It needs to be the following;

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user_contacts = $user->contacts
    return view('contacts.list')->with('contacts', $user_contacts);
}
```

Using `$user->contacts()`(method) will return an instance of the query builder for that relationship, where as `$user->contacts`(property) will return a collection with results from a select query.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access pivot properties of your many to many relationship table u can access with `pivot`

```
    @foreach ($contacts as $contact)
       * {{ $contact->pivot->name }} <br>
    @endforeach
```

Also creates a relatioship between contact and users

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Contat::class)->withPivot(['your', 'pivot','columns']);

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It says "Trying to get property 'pivot' of non-object"

Comment: @Raven have you created a relationship between user and contacts?

Comment: use `->withPivot(['your', 'pivot','columns']);`

Comment: Yes, I have created the relations `->withPivot(['name', 'address']);`

Comment: @Raven you need to change the code in your controller too

Comment: Change to what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166599/discussion-between-laravel-levaral-and-raven).

Answer (score 0):

You must return your pivot table's data in the relation as below:

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Contat::class)->withPivot(['your', 'pivot','columns']);

}
```

And you must get relation data like below:

```
$user_contacts = $user->contacts // Not $user->contacts()
```

Comment: I get an error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'contact_user.name' in 'field list' `

Comment: @Raven Where do you get that error? Edit you question to include model's fields(table's schema).

Comment: I get that error on the index page which is suppose to show a list of logged in user's contacts. I've added table's schema.

Comment: @Raven What is output of `dd($contacts)` in index page?

Comment: @Raven Let us continue this discussion [here in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166616/aspire-me)